# Can not create Umbraco MembersMembershipProvider in unit test

Tags: c#, asp.net, umbraco

I am creating unit tests for my website base on Unit framework. In my unit test, I need to create a MembersMembershipProvider of Umbraco, but it threw null exception:

```
System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Umbraco.Web.Security.Providers.MembersMembershipProvider..ctor()
   at Tests.Controllers.MemberControllerTests.Test_ValidateUser() in
```

This is my unit test:

```
[TestFixture]
public class Test_ProxyMembershipProvider
{
    [Test]
    public void Test_ValidateUser()
    {
        var s = new MembersMembershipProvider();
    }
}
```

What should I fix or I missed something? Any help are highly appreciate!

Cheer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently had the same issue. I was able to resolve the problem by adding an app.config file to my test project.

Within the app.config file, you will need the system.web/membership section. You also need a connectionStrings section, if you are using a Sql provider.

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyDataBase"
   connectionString="data source=localhost;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=MyDataBase"
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <membership defaultProvider="UnitTestSqlMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add
  name="UnitTestSqlMembershipProvider"
  type="Membership.Unit.Provider.UuuSqlMembershipProvider, Membership.Unit.Provider, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral"
  connectionStringName="MyDataBase"
  applicationName="mylittleapp"
  enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
  enablePasswordReset="true"
  requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"
  requiresUniqueEmail="true"
  passwordFormat="Hashed"
  maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="3"
  passwordAttemptWindow="10"
  minRequiredPasswordLength="8"
  minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Additionally, if you want to Mock your provider, then you can create an interface for your custom provider

eg Mock _mbrInfrastructe = new Mock();

at this point you can lean on obj.Setup calls to add additional control over unit tests.

Answer (score 2):

The null reference occurs because the `MembersMembershipProvider` uses `IMembershipMemberService` in the constructor. If you use the constructor without parameters it will try to get the `IMembershipMemberService` from the `ApplicationContext` (which is null since you're running unittests). You can add a mocked version of this service to the constructor parameters:

```
var mServiceMock = new Mock<IMembershipMemberService>();
var s = new MembersMembershipProvider(mServiceMock.Object);
```

For more implementation details of `MembersMembershipProvider` check out the [github sourcecode](https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/blob/7ee510ed386495120666a78c61497f58ff05de8f/src/Umbraco.Web/Security/Providers/MembersMembershipProvider.cs)